# Dialogflow startListening() on keyword

Tags: android, voice-recognition, dialogflow-es

I'm working with the https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client for an Android app that I am building. Rather than setting the startListening() on a button, I'd like it to actively listen for a vocal keyword before activating (think "Hey - Google, Siri, Alexa...").

Currently, I have the voice recognition starting with this button click:

```
public void buttonClicked(final View view) {
    aiService.startListening();
}
```

But I'd like to eliminate the button altogether and get functionality simply through voice.

Answer (score 1):

**Instead of doing this:**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   voiceBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        AIService.startListening();
 });
```

}

**Do this:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AIService.startListening
```

}